# list index out of range - in python

Tags: python-3.x

When I am trying to append data, it gives list index out of range error.

```
n = int(input('Enter Range'))
arr=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i)
    arr[i].append(input('Enter Number'))
arr.sort()
print(arr)
```

Comment: `arr[i].append` should be `arr.append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arr.append() function will append element to the end of the list

```
n = int(input('Enter Range'))
arr=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i)
    arr.append(input('Enter Number')) # Modify this line
arr.sort()
print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I am a newbie and I made a silly mistake.

Comment: for sure buddy.